# Why does k-means have more bias than spectral clustering and GMM?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, computer-science, clustering, artificial-intelligence

I ran into a 2019-Entrance Exam question as follows:

> Which of the following algorithm has the higher bias?
>
> 1. GMM
> 2. GMM (identity covariance matrix)
> 3. spectral clustering
> 4. k-means

The answer mentioned is (4), but some search on google showed me maybe (1) and (2) is equal to (4). Why would k-means be the algorithm with the highest bias? (Can you please also provide references to valid material to study more?)

Comment: I would say because it is the model with the more reduced flexibility in terms of shape of clusters than can fit. K-means is a hard clustering techniques favouring spherical shapes. I do not know if there is really a quantitative / not qualitative to this question, but this is a better place to make this question I think: https://stats.stackexchange.com/